# Possible to monitor URLs an application is connecting to?

Tags: macos, network, applications, monitoring

I'm relatively new to the wondrous world of Apple and Mac OS X so please bear with me..

I have an application which I would like to see which URLs it is "connecting" or "communicating" with. 
Is that at all possible and if so, I would be very glad to be pointed in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: What did you use on Windows? Or are you totally new to such thing to monitor URL's? Is WireShark an option?

Answer (score 3):

### [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/)

A firewall that can alert you when an app connects to a certain domain, and lets you allow/block the connection.

[image: Example Alert]

Alternatively, you can allow all connections and just monitor them.

[image: Network Monitor]

### [Rubbernet](http://rubbernetapp.com)

Alternatively, you can use Rubbernet:

[image: Rubbernet monitor]

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.charlesproxy.com/. Web debugging proxy application that listens to all http & https traffic from your machine to the internet (including all running apps on your computer).